# tableview sort by distance swift

Tags: swift, sorting, mapkit, distance, cllocationcoordinate2d

I build a view mix with map view and table view,I hope I can sort the cell by the distance from user location, I try to use the distanceFromLoaction method, but it shows that CLLocationCoordinate has no member distanceFromLocaiton, is there another way to do it or fix it?

this is my array structure

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class tripSpot: NSObject, MKAnnotation{
var title: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var regionRadius: Double
var location: String?
var type: String?


init(title:String , coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D , regionRadius: Double, location: String, type: String ){
    self.title = title
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.regionRadius = regionRadius
    self.location = location
    self.type = type
  }

  }
```

and my tableviewcode

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapCell") as! mapTableViewCell

    self.tripspot.sort({ $0.coordinate.distanceFromLoaction(self.coordinate) < $1.coordinate.distanceInKilometersTo(self.coordinate)})
    if  searchController.active{
    cell.title.text = searchResults[indexPath.row].title
    cell.location.text = searchResults[indexPath.row].location
    return cell
    }else{
    cell.title.text = tripspot[indexPath.row].title
    cell.location.text = tripspot[indexPath.row].location
    return cell
    }
```

thanks for any advice.

Comment: `distanceFromLocation()` is a `CLLocation` method not a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` one. So you have to transform the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` object into a `CLLocation` (quite easy) then call the `distanceFromLocation()` on it.

Comment: Hi @Larme can you teach me how to turn CLLocationCoordinate2d into CLLocation in swift? I have search all over the stackoverflow , but still can get it. that you.

Comment: `var clLocationObject = CLLocation(latitude: cllocationCoordinate2D.latitude, 
  longitude: cllocationCoordinate2D.longitude)` or something similar.

Comment: sorry for further asking but it shows error,  Instance member 'latitude' cannot be used on type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

final class Places {
var title: String?
var cllocation: CLLocation
var regionRadius: Double
var location: String?
var type: String?
var distance : Double?
var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title:String , cllocation: CLLocation , regionRadius: Double, location: String, type: String ,distance:Double!,coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    self.title = title
    self.cllocation = cllocation
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.regionRadius = regionRadius
    self.location = location
    self.type = type
    self.distance = distance
}


// Function to calculate the distance from given location.
func calculateDistance(fromLocation: CLLocation?) {

    distance = cllocation.distanceFromLocation(fromLocation!)
}
}


let fromLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 24.186965, longitude: 120.633268)

var places:[Places] = [


Places( title: "Title1", cllocation: CLLocation( latitude :24.181143, longitude: 120.593158), regionRadius: 300.0, location: "LocationTitle1", type: "Food",distance : CLLocation( latitude :24.181143, longitude: 120.593158).distanceFromLocation(fromLocation),coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.181143,120.593158)),
Places( title: "Title2", cllocation: CLLocation(latitude:24.14289,longitude:120.679901), regionRadius:150.0, location:"LocationTitle2",type: "Food",distance : CLLocation(latitude:24.14289,longitude:120.679901).distanceFromLocation(fromLocation),coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.14289,120.679901)),
Places( title: "Title3", cllocation: CLLocation(latitude : 24.180407, longitude:120.645086), regionRadius: 300.0, location:"LocationTitle3", type: "Food",distance : CLLocation(latitude : 24.180407, longitude:120.645086).distanceFromLocation(fromLocation),coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.180407,120.645086)),
Places( title: "Title4", cllocation: CLLocation(latitude: 24.149062,longitude:120.684891), regionRadius: 300.0, location: "LocationTitle4", type: "Food",distance : CLLocation(latitude: 24.149062,longitude:120.684891).distanceFromLocation(fromLocation),coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.149062,120.684891)),
Places( title: "Title5", cllocation: CLLocation(latitude:24.138598,longitude:120.672096 ), regionRadius:150.0, location:"LocationTitle5",type: "Food",distance : CLLocation(latitude:24.138598,longitude:120.672096 ).distanceFromLocation(fromLocation),coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.138598,120.672096)),
Places( title: "Title6", cllocation: CLLocation(latitude :24.1333434,longitude:120.680744), regionRadius:100.0, location:"LocationtTitle6",type: "Culture",distance : CLLocation(latitude :24.1333434,longitude:120.680744).distanceFromLocation(fromLocation),coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.1333434,120.680744))

 ]

 for k in 0...(places.count-1) {
      print("\(places[k].distance)")
 }
 for place in places {
      place.calculateDistance(fromLocation) // Replace YOUR_LOCATION           with the location you want to calculate the distance to.
 } 


  places.sortInPlace({ $0.distance < $1.distance }) 

  for n in 0...(places.count-1) {
    print("\(places[n].distance)")
  }
```

Output :

```
//before sort array
Optional(4126.1395817058)
Optional(6803.61030342841)
Optional(1403.39181021788)
Optional(6718.92222011204)
Optional(6653.47447563344)
Optional(7651.92757760459)


//after sort array
Optional(1403.39181021788)
Optional(4126.1395817058)
Optional(6653.47447563344)
Optional(6718.92222011204)
Optional(6803.61030342841)
Optional(7651.92757760459)
```

Comment: I use your method but still can't comply, can u be more specific? thank you.

Comment: your are not able to compare the distance?

Comment: I have no idea how to get distance from two CLLocationCooridinate2D

Comment: you have a location array?

Comment: just add that array in you question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116793/discussion-between-harikrishnan-p-and-johnny-hsieh).